# Convert an inverted canvas to a downloadable image

Tags: javascript, html, image, video, canvas

I've been working on a little page that will work just for doing photos from your webcam and making them downloadable. Everything was okey, I connected the webcam with a video element, and took "screenshot" of a frame and put it with the size I wanted in a canvas element.
The problem is that I wanted to make the photo and the video to look like if they were a mirror. For the video and the canvas element there was no problem, since this CSS code inverts the image perfectly:

```
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Firefox */
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Opera */   
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Chrome y Safari */
  transform: scaleX(-1); /* w3org */
  filter: FlipH; /* Internet Explorer */
```

The problem is that when I convert the canvas to a .png file so the user can download it, the CSS rules set are not respected, so it looks weird that the image is the opposite that it was on video preview.
I can invert it with the same code on browser, but of course that won't change the file that user would download...

So, there's any way to make them to respect the CSS rules? Or at least to invert the image before I create it...?

Update: 
The video I'm playing is took from webcam, you must hit that button that says "START VIDEO". Anyway, on fiddle the html stuff doesn't fit. And yes, the default camera icon on right will be replaced once the user takes the first picture. Once the video starts, there will be three rectangles, from the left the first will be the video preview, the second one is the canvas element and the last one is the image file generated. Everything was tested and working well under a LAMP local setup on Ubuntu 13 and Chromium browser.

Here is my [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jSrAq/)

P.D: This is my [index.html](http://www.mediafire.com/download/h3vwhd4hnh7wtsz/index.html)

Comment: I updated first post with a link to the fiddle

Comment: The video I'm playing is took from webcam, you must hit that button that says "START VIDEO". Anyway, on fiddle the html stuff doesn't fit. And yes, the default camera icon on right will be replaced once the user takes the first picture. Once the video starts, there will be three rectangles, from the left the first will be the video preview, the second one is the canvas element and the last one is the image file generated. Everything was tested and working well under a LAMP local setup on Ubuntu 13 and Chromium browser.

Comment: This is how it looks when you take a pic: http://postimg.org/image/qy4cymv1h/full/

Comment: Is the video preview not starting or what? Javascript console says something?

Comment: yes it says : `Uncaught ReferenceError: getMedia is not defined`

Comment: Lol. Are you sure to have copied the javascript functions? I'm getting an error around "TypeError: Not enough arguments to Navigator.mozGetUserMedia.", but at least the function is called and starts.

Comment: I have done that,:) see this fiddle now.. it works fine but not inverting image.. http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/jSrAq/3/

Comment: I fixed my issue on firefox. Looks like navigator.mozGetUserMedia always expect the last argument while is supposed to be optional, so I defined a failure callback also, and now it works well. Something like:                                                                       // In case an error happened
     function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
     }

Comment: Well now the problem is to find a way to look the picture taken as the preview, but I guess there's no way

Comment: check my fiddle its working fine with preview; just invert is not working.

Comment: CSS styles will *not* be respected you have to actually manipulate the canvas image data directly if you need to save it off to a file.

Comment: This did the magic: ctx.translate(canvas.width, 0); ctx.scale(-1, 1); Thanks a lot :)